# Файл, содержащий переменную innodb_strict_mode

Tags: mysql, sql, битрикс, openserver, innodb

Смотрел https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1cuC3dQFlM&list=PLrHjm4aMLlqKmIGolcjzSL94gF2JnBGPH&index=2 . С 11:00 до 12:00 на экране была ошибка

`Ошибка! innodb_strict_mode=ON, требуется OFF
Переменная sql_mode в MySQL должна быть пустая, текущее значение: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Я открыл файл MySQL-8.0-x64-my.ini (из настроек OpenServer) и не нашел переменной sql_mode:

```
[client]

port                            = %mysqlport%
character_sets_dir              = "%dprogdir%\\modules\\database\\%mysql_driver%\\share\\charsets"

[mysql]

no-auto-rehash
no-beep
character_sets_dir              = "%dprogdir%\\modules\\database\\%mysql_driver%\\share\\charsets"

[mysqld]

# Required Settings

basedir                         = "%dprogdir%\\modules\\database\\%mysql_driver%"
bind-address                    = %ip%
character_sets_dir              = "%dprogdir%\\modules\\database\\%mysql_driver%\\share\\charsets"
character_set_server            = utf8mb4
collation_server                = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
datadir                         = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\%mysql_driver%"
default_authentication_plugin   = mysql_native_password
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
ft_min_word_len                 = 3
local_infile                    = 0
lower_case_table_names          = 1
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
mysqlx                          = 0
pid_file                        = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\temp\\mysql.pid"
port                            = %mysqlport%
secure-file-priv                = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\php_upload"
#skip_name_resolve              = 1
ssl                             = 0
tmpdir                          = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\temp"

# Buffer Settings

bulk_insert_buffer_size         = 8M
join_buffer_size                = 2M
read_buffer_size                = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 4M
sort_buffer_size                = 2M

# Connection Settings

max_connections                 = 64
max_connect_errors              = 32
back_log                        = 512
thread_cache_size               = 8
interactive_timeout             = 180
wait_timeout                    = 180

# InnoDB Settings

innodb_adaptive_hash_index      = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 128M
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir            = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\%mysql_driver%"
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
#innodb_force_recovery          = 1
innodb_log_file_size            = 64M
innodb_read_io_threads          = 8
#innodb_thread_concurrency      = 4
innodb_write_io_threads         = 8
innodb_strict_mode              = OFF

# Logging

%log%general_log                = 1
%log%general_log_file           = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\logs\\%mysql_driver%_queries.log"
log_error                       = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\logs\\%mysql_driver%_error.log"
log_bin                         = 0
#log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
#long_query_time                = 5
#slow_query_log                 = 1
#slow_query_log_file            = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\logs\\%mysql_driver%_slow.log"

# MyISAM Settings

key_buffer_size                 = 32M
myisam_max_sort_file_size       = 256M
myisam_recover_options          = backup,force

# Table Settings

table_definition_cache          = 10000
table_open_cache                = 10000
open_files_limit                = 60000
max_heap_table_size             = 128M
tmp_table_size                  = 128M

[mysqldump]

quick
quote_names
max_allowed_packet              = 16M

[myisamchk]

key_buffer_size                 = 64M
sort_buffer_size                = 64M
read_buffer                     = 2M
write_buffer                    = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]

interactive-timeout

[mysqld_safe]

open_files_limit                = 60000
```

В каком файле нужно задать sql_mode? 
P.S. Со sql_mode разобрался, а на innodb все равно ругается

```
    Ошибка! innodb_strict_mode=ON, требуется OFF
```

даже несмотря на добавленный в раздел innodb соответствующей директивы

```
# InnoDB Settings

innodb_adaptive_hash_index      = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 128M
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir            = "%dprogdir%\\userdata\\%mysql_driver%"
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
#innodb_force_recovery          = 1
innodb_log_file_size            = 64M
innodb_read_io_threads          = 8
#innodb_thread_concurrency      = 4
innodb_write_io_threads         = 8
innodb_strict_mode              = OFF
```

Подскажите как убрать ошибку с innodb.

Comment: Параметр `sql-mode` в файле конфигурации (my.ini), секция [mysqld]. *не нашел переменной sql_mode* Создай...

Comment: в секции mysqld